# Cocos2d v3 enable Retina removed?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The new version of cocos2d doesn't seem to scale images for Retina display.
On the previous version you could just do this:

```
[director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES];
```

The method doesn't seem to exist anymore.  Any idea how to implement this on v3?

Comment: Not needed as cocos2d v3 behaves as if this were always enabled. Is it possible that you did not include a -hd version of your images?

Comment: Thank you sir, however this doesn't seem to exist on the docs and in my opinion the previous method to do this is much more flexible than say rename your assets to have "-hd" on them.

Comment: There's a lot of things missing from the docs currently. In previous versions Retina display was always enabled anyway, and since Apple started to require use of Retina assets it stopped making sense to disable Retina mode (on Retina devices). You don't have to rename your assets, you have to provide either Retina-sized images without suffix (if you don't plan on supporting any Retina devices) or provide both standard and Retina resolution versions, ie "image.png" and "image-hd.png" with 2x the size of image.png.

Comment: That's the problem all my assets are Retina-sized images(without suffix) cause my game only supports Retina devices.  And just now I found out that while in v2 I could easily use Apportable to port them to Android devices without any problem but now on v3 I've tried all the different UIScreenMode and most of the images are offscreen.  Any thoughts on this problem as well?

Comment: Look into CCFileUtils. You can bend and tweak suffixes per device as you like. If your -hd assets don't use the suffix, change that suffix string to @"" and it will load regularly named files.

Comment: Yup already did that just now thanks!